# GWT: use DateTimeFormat on client and SimpleDateFormat on server

Tags: gwt

I have a function that must work the same way on both client and server and it formats dates.

```
if (GWT.isClient())
{
  // Use DateTimeFormat
} else {
  // Use SimpleDateFormat
}
```

GWT complains: No source code is available for type SimpleDateFormat. The error is not fatal (at least in dev mode), but annoying and no way to suppress it.
Found a similar question on http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/981247fca161c287 . There they suggest:

> You can provide a dummy supersource implementation of
>   SimpleDateTimeFormat so that it would compile.

I tried. Now Eclipse complains:

> java.text
>   The declared package "java.text" does not match the expected package "foo.jre.java.text"    SimpleDateFormat.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell Eclipse not to compile your super-source'd Java file. If you're using Maven, it's simply a matter of moving it to src/main/resources; otherwise, exclude your 'jre' *package* from Eclipse's build path.

...that being said, I'd rather super-source the class the uses the SimpleDateFormat/DateTimeFormat, and/or move that to a helper class that you'd super-source.

Answer (score 34):

You can use `com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat` on both server and client:

Call the protected constructor to avoid GWT.create

```
String pattern = "yyyyMMdd"; /*your pattern here*/ 
DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo info = new DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo();
DateTimeFormat dtf = new DateTimeFormat(pattern, info) {};  // <= trick here
```

Example

```
Date d = dtf.parse("20120301");
CalendarUtil.addDaysToDate(d, -1);
String s = dtf.format(d);
// s now contains "20120229"
```

The trick is done by extending the `DateTimeFormat` so we can use protected constructor with `DateTimeFormatInfo` where we use the `new DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo()` to avoid calling of `GWT.create`

Comment: The constructor DateTimeFormat(String, DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo) is undefined

Answer (score 3):

```
import com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat;
DateTimeFormat fm = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MM/dd");
String st = fm.format(date);
```

Comment: Very neat solution.

Comment: Doesn't work because `getFormat` internally uses `LocaleInfo` which is in the client package again. It's a GWT bug.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is a bit different but in the same path of the one @ochakov presented but it resolves the GWT 2.7 problem @stepancheg and I mentioned.

```
import java.util.Date;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.annotations.GwtCompatible;
import com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.annotations.GwtIncompatible;

public abstract class DateTimeFormat {
    static DateTimeFormat getFormat(String pattern)
    {
        if (GWT.isClient())
            return new DateTimeFormatClient(pattern);
        else
            return new DateTimeFormatServer(pattern);
    }

    public abstract String format(Date date);

    public abstract Date parse(String dateString);

    @GwtCompatible
    private static class DateTimeFormatClient extends DateTimeFormat
    {
        protected String pattern;

        public DateTimeFormatClient(String pattern)
        {
            this.pattern = pattern;
        }


        public String format(Date date)
        {
            return com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat.getFormat(pattern).format(date);
        }

        public Date parse(String stringDate){
            return com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat.getFormat(pattern).parseStrict(stringDate);
        }
    }

    private static class DateTimeFormatServer extends DateTimeFormatClient
    {

        public DateTimeFormatServer(String pattern)
        {
            super(pattern);
        }


        @GwtIncompatible("Server format")
        public String format(Date date)
        {
            return (new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(pattern)).format(date);
        }  

        @GwtIncompatible("Server parse")
        public Date parse(String dateString){
            try{
                return (new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(pattern)).parse(dateString);
            }catch(Exception ex){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot convert to date: "+ dateString);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this help others.

Comment: Unfortunately just moves the error: The type `DateTimeFormat.DateTimeFormatServer must implement the inherited abstract method DateTimeFormat.format(Date)` - GWT 2.8

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Date;

import com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.annotations.GwtCompatible;
import com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.annotations.GwtIncompatible;

public abstract class DateTimeFormat
{
    static DateTimeFormat getFormat(String pattern)
    {
        if (GWT.isClient())
            return DateTimeFormatClient.getFormat(pattern);
        else
            return DateTimeFormatServer.getFormat(pattern);
    }

    public abstract String format(Date date);

    @GwtCompatible
    private static class DateTimeFormatClient extends DateTimeFormat
    {
        private com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat dateTimeFormat;

        protected DateTimeFormatClient(String pattern)
        {
            this.dateTimeFormat = com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat.getFormat(pattern);
        }

        public static DateTimeFormat getFormat(String pattern)
        {
            return new DateTimeFormatClient(pattern);
        }

        public String format(Date date)
        {
            return dateTimeFormat.format(date);
        }
    }

    @GwtIncompatible("Server version of the class")
    private static class DateTimeFormatServer extends DateTimeFormat
    {
        private java.text.SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat;

        protected DateTimeFormatServer(String pattern)
        {
            this.dateTimeFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        }

        public static DateTimeFormat getFormat(String pattern)
        {
            return new DateTimeFormatServer(pattern);
        }

        public String format(Date date)
        {
            return dateTimeFormat.format(date);
        }       

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this need @GwtIncompatible from http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=11570 has it been released?

Comment: this is now released in GWT 2.6 (but you are right, it was not in 2.5.1 or earlier)

Comment: Doesn't work in GWT 2.7: `The method getFormat(String) is undefined for the type DateTimeFormat.DateTimeFormatServer`

Comment: I have the same problem that @stepancheg mentioned, same error, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat;

DateTimeFormat dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(DateTimeFormat.PredefinedFormat.DATE_MEDIUM);
String stringDate = dateTimeFormat.format(date);
```

where date is a Java.util.Date object