# Convert a date of String type to java.util.Date type without using SimpleDateFormat or Calendar

Tags: java, date, gwt, date-conversion

I'm fetching a date which is of String type but I need the Date type of it. I'm working in a gwt project so I cannot use SimpleDateFormat or Calendar (which doesn't work in the runtime and throws source code not found exception)

new Date(stringDate) is deprecated so any other way I could do it?

Comment: Try this, to get SimpleDateFormat working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284564/gwt-use-datetimeformat-on-client-and-simpledateformat-on-server

Answer (score 2):

Consider using DateTimeFormat:
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html

Comment: I'm sorry this ain't working I'm getting the following exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 2014-09-30 13:09:01.047 at com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat.parse(DateTimeFormat.java:1437) at com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat.parse(DateTimeFormat.java:882)

Comment: What date pattern are you using?

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
String myString = "Thu Nov 18 11:53:45 BST 2014";
DateTimeFormat sdf = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("EEE MM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date myDate = sdf.parse(myString);
```

For more details check [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html)
I hope this could help!

Comment: I'm sorry this ain't working I'm getting the following exception

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 2014-09-30 13:09:01.047
 at com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat.parse(DateTimeFormat.java:1437)
 at com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat.parse(DateTimeFormat.java:882)

Comment: this is the date which I'm retrieving from the db
2014-09-30 13:09:01.047

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parse()` function of `DateTimeFormat` class from `com.google.gwt.i18n.client` package
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/shared/DateTimeFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: I'm sorry this ain't working I'm getting the following exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 2014-09-30 13:09:01.047 at com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat.parse(DateTimeFormat.java:1437) at com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat.parse(DateTimeFormat.java:882)

Comment: Which string are you using for the format ? It should be someting like DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse("2014-09-30 13:09:01.047");

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `Date (java.sql.Date)` in the format `yyy-mm-dd` you can call

`Date.valueOf("1996-12-12")` which returns a `Date` instance

If you use `Date (java.util.Date)` you can call

`new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())` which returns a `Date` instance

**Edit**
GWT has [DateTimeFormat](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) which you can use