# GWT compilation fails due to SimpleDateFormat [LIBGDX]

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx

As you may know `SimpleDateFormat` is not support by GWT. However I could not find an any alternative so far.

```
public Player(String name, int score, Date dateScore){
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
    this.dateScore = dateScore;
    if(dateScore != null){
        this.dateScoreFormatted = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(dateScore);
    }   
}
```

This guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284564/gwt-use-datetimeformat-on-client-and-simpledateformat-on-server) says to import `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat`, but I have no idea how to import it. Will this work on **native** Android and Desktop app as well with Libgdx?

Answer (score 2):

GWT code compiles to JavaScript. It will work in every supported browser, including mobile and desktop browsers.

So yes, you need to use `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat`.

Comment: thanks....but I am using the framework libgdx which converts java code to native android apps and desktop applications. So on Android users will be using the app itself and not the browser version.

Comment: It would helpful to mention that you mean _native_ Android app and _Java_ desktop app.

Comment: thanks @noone...I completely forgot about the specific code implementation. I think needed a very good rest after a full day of coding.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Noone who made the things clear for me.

In case someone else needs it, you can use an `ActionResolver` and import the correct classes supported by each platform. [See specific code implementation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code)

This is how it works for me now for HTML5 version:

```
public class HtmlLauncher extends GwtApplication implements com.yourpackage.util.ActionResolver{

    @Override
    public GwtApplicationConfiguration getConfig () {
            return new GwtApplicationConfiguration(360, 640);
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationListener getApplicationListener () {
            return new MyGame(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String convertDate(String format, Date date) {
        DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo info = new DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo();
        DateTimeFormat dateFormat = new DateTimeFormat(format, info) {}; 

        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    @Override
    public Date parseDate(String format, String date) {
        DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo info = new DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo();
        DateTimeFormat dateFormat = new DateTimeFormat(format, info) {}; 

        return dateFormat.parse(date);
    }
}
```

For the Android and Desktop `ActionResolvers` you can use SimpleDateFormat normally...