# Why does com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat call Gwt.create

Tags: gwt

In my shared code I replaced `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat` with `com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat` to avoid runtime issues with `Gwt.create` as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38603243/2756574).

My problem is now, that `DateTimeFormat.getFormat` calls `getDefaultDateTimeFormatInfo` which calls `LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getDateTimeFormatInfo()`. `LocaleInfo` is a singleton which is instanciated via `new LocaleInfo((LocaleInfoImpl)GWT.create(LocaleInfoImpl.class), (CldrImpl)GWT.create(CldrImpl.class))`.

In my test this ends up in an `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

```java
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat.getDefaultDateTimeFormatInfo(DateTimeFormat.java:681)
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.DateTimeFormat.getFormat(DateTimeFormat.java:665)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: ERROR: GWT.create() is only usable in client code!  It cannot be called, for example, from server code.  If you are running a unit test, check that your test case extends GWTTestCase and that GWT.create() is not called from within an initializer or constructor.
    at com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.create(GWT.java:66)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:86)
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.client.LocaleInfo.<clinit>(LocaleInfo.java:36)
    ... 27 more
```

So I'm really surprised that a shared class calls `Gwt.create` at all. In my understanding of how GWT works, this should not be the case. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least I think, this is a known issue: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/7668

Instead, you can give:

https://github.com/vegegoku/gwt-i18n-apt

a try.

But not sure, if it is already migrated completly. You may ask this here: https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt-modules